# How likely is it that my kids will break this bench?

Tags: joinery, design, racking

I need a bench for our kitchen table, and am trying to teach myself basic joinery, so I'm attempting to build one from some scrap pallet wood.

The wood is nominally 1x4 and I think is probably pine, though that's a lesser concern. As I'm new to this, I'd like feedback to ensure the design itself isn't critically flawed.

The expected load will be various combinations of my three kids (ages 9, 6, and 2). They all fidget, though the only one I expect will jump on it would be the 2 year old.

Here's the basic design:
[image: Screenshot from Sketchup]

The top connects to the legs by a series of through mortises holding the outer planks in place. The inner plank is held by a dado that notches into a bit of wood acts as a spacer (I'm not sure if this is properly a tenon or not). This serves two functions: it widens the seat slightly, and minimizes the chance that spills will accumulate food gunk between the planks of the bench top.

Here's a closeup of the connection between the legs and top:
[image: Connection between legs and top, over and under views]

Here's a shot with the top planks hidden, showing the location and size of the tenons:
[image: Tenons at top of legs]

The thinnest place the wood gets is at the half-laps which connect the legs together. I've tried to mitigate this by compressing the half-lap between the tusk and the shoulder of the tenon, though I don't know how effective this will be:
[image: Detail of half-lap compression]

In the short term, it looks like it'll be ok - I'm currently adding the lower struts as there was some racking when we tried it out without them and my kids started to fidget.

I'm a bit concerned on how long it's likely to last, and if it's probably going to break, any tips on making the next version more durable would be very welcome.

Comment: The design is in the SketchUp Web App, and they don't seem to have figured out how to share designs yet, so let me know what other views would be helpful and I'll add more screenshots.

Comment: There's a lot of variables here still.  How thick is the wood you're using?  Are you gluing all/some/any of the joints?  How is the top attached?   (I can see through tenons in the image but they span across the gaps between seat slats, which doesn't make sense.)

Comment: Overall I think it looks fine.  The thing I'd probably worry about most is the thickness of the legs in the half-lap joints, but short of a total redesign I don't know what you could do about that.

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232 Thanks for looking it over. I've added some additional screenshots of the connection between the legs and the top, and information about the half-lap I used to connect the legs. I'm currently not planning on gluing it, as my kids can be messy eaters (our youngest is 2) and I'd like to be able to break it down for cleaning, but I'm not married to no glue as a design principle.

Comment: I've voted to close as this is a little broad, and while there appears to be ample detail provided the only clear, distinct Question is the thread title, and really that can't be answered because of all the things we can't know (including how much abuse it will take!) but above all the greatest unknowns are the wood (+ its condition) and the quality of the joinery. Build this exactly as pictured from clear pine and this would be literally impossible to break in the normal course of events, but it's pallet wood and we don't know how many knots there are, how much weathering it's taken etc. etc.

Comment: One tip for future projects that I wanted to add in case the SketchUp images exactly reflect the way this is built, use shallower angles for your wedges. 8-10° is good, these look like they're closer to 30° which is way too steep unless the tusk tenons are purely decorative.

Comment: Thanks @Graphus, that's exactly the sort of feedback I need. Mainly I'm looking for design feedback. If the wood's not able to handle the stresses that's one thing, I'd like to avoid reworking the design if that's not the problem. I'll edit the question to be more clear about that

Comment: @Graphus WRT the quality of execution, that's a lesser concern. I'm currently producing joints that could generously be called "amateurish", but if the bench breaks and the design is good, I'll just make another (hopefully with better executed joinery).

Comment: Some further feedback on this one then, I think it's very likely that you should glue the overlap joints (the half-laps) and if necessary add a couple of screw too. The tusk tenon through those would be intended to hold each pair of legs quite firmly together, but that is predicated on everything being cut good and tight and the wedge finally tensioning everything nicely. If those overlaps are able to shift even slightly the whole assembly can have bit of play, so rigidly fixed you'll gain a lot of stability. I think you'll be surprised by how much difference it makes.

Comment: I'd echo the concern above that nominal 1" pine legs can be a little too weak, especially given that the half laps are going to be punctured by the tenon. If your upper strut could be vertical and maybe taller -- 1x6? -- that would help a lot with side to side racking. (I know that messes the wedge a little.)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I don't have wider wood on hand, would the hassle of gluing filler in the mortise and rechopping it so the upper strut is vertical be worth it if the shoulder is the same size?

Comment: Given that the mortise/tenon is already done, I'd leave everything as is and file the alternate details away for the next iteration. (If the current one turned out really wobbly, a subtle L bracket underneath would probably help with the racking.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the occupants of the bench rock to the left and right, the wedge will apply a large force on the end of the pegged tenon. The expected failure point is marked in the image. A combined weight of 150lbs, doing moderate rocking, could cause this failure in a few seconds.

[image: expected failure point in pegged tenon]

Comment: Good to know, are there ways to mitigate this? I'd imagine this would be a weakness in most tables and benches that use wedged tenons in their uprights.

Comment: @Morgen, this is a possible failure but the risk is being overstated *considerably*, because whether it can occur at all is entirely dependent on the flow of grain through the tenon, which isn't known. And even if the grain is in the worst possible orientation (not at all likely) it's *still* not a guaranteed failure. But since you asked there are two main ways to reduce the risk of this, #1 is off the table since your bench is already made so it's option #2, which is to reinforce the end of the tenon with a tight-fitting dowel glued in horizontally. Hardwood dowel ideally.

Comment: The tusk tenon will be substantially stronger if a long mortise is made on the thin side. This would leave more wood to hold the end of the horizontal support together. Refer to this video on wedged tusk tenons: https://www.pbs.org/video/woodwrights-shop-wedged-tusk-tenon/

Comment: @StephenMeschke thanks for the link, it was really informative. I'm going to recut the keys at a gentler angle, and adjust the design for a longer tenon (for the next one). As is, I think it'll be OK, as the tenon ended up being a bit larger than in the design (I got lazy about trimming them down)

Answer (score 2):

The weakest point ended up being the half-laps (as predicted by @SaSSafraS1232):

[image: Lengthwise crack in the leg]

Comment: SE is not like a forum, it's a Q&A site and you've posted where an Answer should go. You should delete this and add it as an update to the Question.

Comment: True, SE is not a forum, however self-answered questions are permissible. In this case, I elected to put this as an answer for two reasons: 1. It is an answer to the question, and answering a question in the question itself doesn't seem appropriate. 2. The correct answer had been left as a comment, so my intention was also to convert that information into an actual answer. Should @SaSSafraS1232 be willing to swing back and convert their comment into an answer, I'd be inclined to upvote that and delete this.